# Trying to deploy React Webpack app to Heroku, keep getting 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./src/index.js"' error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to deploy to Heroku, and build is successful; however, a blank screen is up and the console has error:

```
'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./src/index.js"'
```

Also, while deploying, I have the following error:

```
ERROR in Loader
/tmp/build_ad82f59a947c9639c358909b17671d27/node_modules/babel/index.js?{"presets":["react","es2015","stage-1"]} didn't return a function
```

In my local environment, I have a .env file with my private access tokens and I use DotEnv to retrieve those secret keys when I make an API call. Also I have already set my config variables on Heroku. But when I look in Heroku logs, I get error:

```
2016-09-12T22:16:15.191754+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-09-12T22:16:15.191755+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-12T22:16:15.686543+00:00 app[web.1]: { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }
```

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
entry: [
  './src/index.js'
],
output: {
  path: __dirname,
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
loaders: [{
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
  }
},
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loaders: ['babel'],
  exclude: /node_modules/
},
{ 
  test: /\.css$/, 
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' 
},
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
  loader: 'url?limit=25000'
}]
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  contentBase: './'
}
};
```

Here's my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
  "enzyme": "^2.4.1",
  "jquery": "^2.2.1",
  "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
  "mocha": "^2.4.5",
  "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.13.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
  "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
  "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "lodash": "^3.10.1",
  "material-ui": "^0.15.2",
  "react": "^15.3.0",
  "react-dom": "^15.0.0",
  "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
  "react-router": "^2.0.1",
  "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
  "react-tweet": "^1.0.22",
  "redux": "^3.0.4",
  "twitter": "^1.3.0",
  "webpack": "^1.12.9"
}
}
```

Here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var DotEnv = require('dotenv');

DotEnv.config();

const api_twitter_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});

// configure express to use body-parser as middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '500mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '500mb' }));

// serve static files like index.html, css etc
app.use( express.static( __dirname ) );

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname), 'index.html');
});

app.post('/api/getTweets', function(req, res) {

  var params = { q: req.body.searchQuery + '+everlane', filter: 'media' };

  client.get(api_twitter_url, params, function(error, tweets, resp) {

      if (error) { console.log('error: ', error) }

      if (!error) {
        res.send(tweets);
      }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
   console.log('\nProduction Express server running at localhost:' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your server configuration? Are you using Express?

Comment: Just posted server.js above. Thanks! @samcorcos

Comment: you're sure the build was successful? How are you sure? And can you include your `index.html` file as well?

Comment: @Jenna, this seems to be a common problem, I am having it and so is a colleague of mine. Maybe provide a minimal version of your `server.js` file. With just `const` of `express`, `path`, `port`, and `app` and `app.use()`, `app.get()` and `app.listen()`. Just so as not to scare people away.